# Override an environmental variable on Azure App Service without using the app settings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I need to override one of the default Azure environmental variables. The most obvious way is to add an app setting with the same name, which will override the environmental variable, however, I'd like to approach it in a different way, as this variable is essentially not an app settings.

My perfect approach would be to set it during an ARM deployment, but after checking Azure Resource Explorer, it looks like the environmental variables are not exposed anywhere. Are those stored in some files on the machine that could be transformed during a deployment by any chance? That could be another solution.

Comment: Please give details on the specific one you're trying to change, and why. They're not all the same.

Comment: Hey @DavidEbbo, the env var I need to change is WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE. It used to be 0, but has suddenly changed to 1, which in turn nuked our site. Hence the need to keep it on 0, until I actually figure out what it does, why was it changed and why does that break the site.

Comment: It's strange that it would suddenly change. ARe you sure it's not currently listed in your App Settings? App Settings is normally where this goes. And does it fix the problem if you set it back to 0 explicitly from the App Settings?

Comment: Hey @DavidEbbo, Yes it is. I thought that it was something that got deployed with the last ARM deployment, but then I found a resource group that was untouched for over a month and also had it changed. Setting it back to 0 does help, however we couldn't find in the documentation what does this setting actually do and why the site breaks when it's on 1.

Comment: Discussing the semantics of `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` is I think too far outside the scope of your original question, which is about overriding environment variables. It's best to tackle that part separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My perfect approach would be to set it during an ARM deployment, but after checking Azure Resource Explorer, it looks like the environmental variables are not exposed anywhere.

In ARM template, we could [define the Application Settings](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/03/azure-arm-template-define-web-app-application-settings/) to apply to the Web App. As David Ebbo said, please try to explicitly set `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` to 0 from the appsettings.

```
{
    "name": "appsettings",
    "type": "config",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
    ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "WebAppSettings"
  },
  "properties": {
    "WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE": "0"
  }
}
```

***Update:***

I do not find a resource/section in ARM template could be used to directly inject an environment variable. [XDT Transform](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples) provide a way to inject environment variables, if possible, you could try to use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">  
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">    
         <add name="WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE" value="0" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hello, as I said, I know about this possibility, however, we want to define it outside of application settings, because it's not an application setting after all.

Comment: Cool, thanks. This might be just what I'm looking for. I'll test it out tomorrow or on Monday and see if it works.

Comment: Hi @Slowacki, any updates? it works on my side, do you test it?

Comment: Hey there. We upload an applicationHost transform file periodically and putting your code in there did work. Thanks a lot :)